# It's possible to run an .NET Native Image executable?

Tags: .net, windows, native, .net-assembly, cil

The question is simple: i've generated an executable with `ngen`, his full path is:

```
"C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\NassilDotNet\eddb174e4a81e440633abddb977ab57a\NassilDotNet.ni.exe"
```

When I try to open/execute that executeable, an Error Message Dialog is displayed: This application cannot be runned on your system. Please, contact computer administrator (etc)...

The original executeable shows an Hello World message on Console.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Native images are launched by the CLR when the original executable is launched (it skips the JIT process that the executable would otherwise be subject to) so you're not meant to open them directly. I feel it's a mistake by Microsoft to name the generated images `.exe`.

Comment: The original executeable content stills stored on the output image, so, how someone can execute that?

Comment: Please rephrase "The original executeable content stills stored on the output image" - I don't understand you.

Comment: The output of NGEN is the addition of the X86 assembly in the original executeable to run in assembly code, but this code is stored with the original in the same output file. So could only run the X86 generated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several differences in *ngen* assemblies from the normal ones. First, they are always marked `IL_LIBRARY`, even if they are executable. You can see this if you open the manifest in *ildasm*:

```
.corflags 0x00000004    //  IL_LIBRARY
```

Whereas normal assemblies usually have `.corflags 0x00000001` (`ILONLY`) even if they are only libraries.

Second, (even though they are *.exe*), the standard PE entry point is missing (and the DOS entry point is missing too). It doesn't really matter much for CIL executables, but there are already two signs to tell the system it shouldn't execute the executable.

I thought a code like this could work:

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
ass.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[]{new string[]{}});
```

But I always get *BadImageFormatException* in *LoadFile*. Strangely, I don't get this exception if I load a library file this way, but that has no entry point that can be invoked.

I suppose you can disassemble the file with *ildasm*, change the `.corflags` field and use *ilasm* to produce an executable. However, this will strip the native code present in the file and turn it basically to the original executable.

To sum this up, just run the original file. *ngen* files are part of the framework infrastructure and aren't meant to be deployed or run directly.